# How are non-standard tags processed by browser?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am refactoring a legacy code and seeing there some custom non-standard tags like this:

```
<close></close>
```

As these are not [custom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Custom_Elements), but just work as `divs`, I am inclined to remove these and replace with structures like this:

```
<div class="close"></div>
```

Meanwhile I am wondering if elements with tags that are not from this list https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ are processed somehow differently by browsers and if they require more resources to be processed or not?

Comment: Unknown elements take the initial values of all non-inherited CSS properties, which for `display` is `inline`, so they are more like `<span>` than `<div>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the only interesting thing to note is that unknown elements such as the `<close></close>` element in the question expose [`HTMLUnknownElement` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLUnknownElement) in the DOM.

Otherwise there’s nothing exceptional about how browsers process them. The HTML parsers in browsers parse them into the DOM just as they would normal known elements.

As far as the part of the question about whether unknown elements require more resources to be processed: given that browsers don’t do anything special with them, the browser resource requirements for handling them are no different than they would be for a `div` or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

You can read the article to know more information: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/

They do not require more resources to be processed them because of it like a `standard-tag`.

Note when using `non-standard-tag`:

- No Google will not penalise your site for using non-standard HTML tags in Html document. But When we talk about Google, it is all about Google bots and search engine results. When bots index or read your page it checks for type of document, based on the type it crawls your site. Basically by using custom tags which are not standard as per doctype you are confusing those bots which may result in put less weight on your content and may not show in search results.
- It looks better to you. But you will have to think about cross browser compatibility too after all you are writing it for the world. Some browser would render it in a different way especially IE. So it is good to practice using standard Html tags.
- In jquery, Selector concept is same for all elements. Again it might break in IE if use custom tags.

Answer (score 1):

Non-standard elements are processed just like simple `<div>`.

But it may have different meaning. E.g. `<div class="section">` and `<section>` has different semantic meaning to some page crawlers (like Google bot).

Also there may be some JS code that works with these tags, changing it will break JS code.

E.g. `$('close')` will not work with `<div class="close">`

---

Html is nothing more than XML, so any tag can be written to HTML with any kind of attributes. It does matter only when some tool is processing these tags.